# configure sqlcmd to automatically run your script every time it starts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a sqlcmd startup script that i have stored in c:\myscript.sql, and I want it to run every time i start sqlcmd. 
     how do I configure sqlcmd to automatically run your script every time it starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented in [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)

> E. Using a startup script
>
> A sqlcmd startup script is executed when sqlcmd is started. The following example sets the environment variable SQLCMDINI. This is the contents of init.sql.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
DECLARE @nt_username nvarchar(128)
SET @nt_username = (SELECT rtrim(convert(nvarchar(128), nt_username))
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE spid = @@SPID)
SELECT @nt_username + ' is connected to ' +
rtrim(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), SERVERPROPERTY('servername'))) +
' (' +
rtrim(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))) +
')'
:setvar SQLCMDMAXFIXEDTYPEWIDTH 100
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
:setvar SQLCMDMAXFIXEDTYPEWIDTH
```

> This calls the init.sql file when sqlcmd is started.

```
C:\> SET sqlcmdini=c:\init.sql
>1 Sqlcmd
```

> This is the output.

```
>1 < user > is connected to < server > (9.00.2047.00)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the SQLCMDINI variable in Windows.  For example:

C:\SET SQLCMDINI=c:\sqlscripts\init.sql

The init.sql (or whatever you name it) would contain the initial script.